# Auto-resizing Cell not updating height on first load

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom tableViewCell:

[image]

The `Extra text` label sometimes is hidden so the cell should autoresize.

This `Extra text` label is hidden setting the .active = NO; for the rules around the label:

```
-(void)setShowExtraText:(BOOL)showExtraText
{
    _showExtraText = showExtraText;
    if (showExtraText) {

        self.textfieldBottomSuperviewConstraint.active = NO;

        self.extraText.hidden = NO;

        self.textfieldExtraTextConstraint.active = YES;
        self.leadingExtraTextConstraint.active = YES;
        self.extraTextBottomContraint.active = YES;
    }
    else{
        self.extraText.hidden = YES;

        self.textfieldExtraTextConstraint.active = NO;
        self.leadingExtraTextConstraint.active = NO;
        self.textfieldBottomSuperviewConstraint.active = YES;
        self.extraTextBottomContraint.active = NO;
    }
}
```

There is only one cell with has the `Extra text` label no hidden, and this is the last one in the tableView.

The problem is when the tableView loads the heigh of the cells are wrong. Also taking a look the `Debug View Hierarchy` it shows is ignoring the code to desactivate the rules. Because the rules desactivated are still in the view.

If I do scroll down and scroll up the layout of the cells are right, showing the the one with the Extra text and the ones without the extra text correctly.

I tried adding:

```
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
```

I tried to using SizeClasses. ( I wasn't using sizeClasses before )

I run out of ideas, any idea?

Thanks

---

Update 1

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithExtraText" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [cell setShowExtraText:(indexPath.section == LOGIN_SECTION && indexPath.row == REPEAT_PASSWORD_ROW)];

        return cell;
}
```

---

Update 2

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithExtraText" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [cell setShowExtraText:(indexPath.section == LOGIN_SECTION && indexPath.row == REPEAT_PASSWORD_ROW)];

        [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

        [self.tableView setNeedsLayout];
        [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];    

        return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At:

> CellForRowAtIndexPath

Before returning the cell, call

> updateConstraintsIfNeeded

At you example you do not show the **CellForRowAtIndexPath** method at all.
Make sure you call your **setShowExtraText** before calling **updateConstraintsIfNeeded**

And on the table view call:

```
[self.tableView setNeedsLayout];
[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
```

After

> ReloadData

After that, every time you will want to update your cell height without reloading all tableView, just cell

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I added updateConstraintsIfNeeded after setShowExtraText in the CellForRowAtIndexPath but it's still doing the same. 

I guess I need to do [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded]. But I tried with [tableView updateConstraintsIfNeeded] too. Neither of them worked. Thanks

Comment: You are right, I've checked my code and every reload I'm calling "setNeedsLayout" and "layoutIfNeeded" on my tableView. And "beginUpdates" and "endUpdates" on cell height change. (I'm using resizingCell with AutoLayout)

Comment: I tried as you said, in the update 2 and it's still not working. Thanks :)

Comment: @xarly   The calls for updating the table view (begin end update, set needs display etc) should be after to call reloadTable view. Not inside cellForRow

Comment: MCMatan, but reload the table is too much effort for the tableView. It could be a solution, but in general I tried not to call reloadTable because it too expensive for the performance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem when you activate and deactivate autolayout rules.

It works ok if you change characteristics either in the rules or/and views.

For example this is the solution which works perfectly:

```
 -(void)setShowExtraText:(BOOL)showExtraText
 {
     _showExtraText = showExtraText;

     if (showExtraText) {
         [self.extraText setContentCompressionResistancePriority:750 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
         [self.extraText setContentCompressionResistancePriority:750 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
     }
     else{
         [self.extraText setContentCompressionResistancePriority:1 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
         [self.extraText setContentCompressionResistancePriority:1 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
     }
 }
```

I don't have to do any update in the table with

```
   [self.tableView beginUpdates];
   [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

nor

```
   [self.tableView setNeedsLayout];
   [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Just works.

Obviously this is a work around because I wouldn't like to have the label `Extra text` in the hierarchy. With this solution the label is still there but the height and the width is 0.

I hope it helps someone.

Thanks @MCMatan for your ideas, made me get the solution :)